# struct - best way to use sizeof()

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I have the following struct and a pointer to it.

```
struct abc  
{  
   int val;

};
struct abc* ptr;
```

What is the best way to use sizeof() for this structure
`sizeof(struct abc)` or `sizeof(*ptr)`

I understand both implies the same outcome in most cases, but I would like to know about the corner cases in which one would be better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The corner case is if you change `ptr` so it points to a different struct,
or if you forget what `ptr` is pointing to, or the person maintaining your code doesn't know but wants it to be correct.
So I vote for the second one.